# Why am I always unable to push changes on github - dual profiles

Tags: git, github

I have 2 github profiles :
username: personal, username: professional
I generated 2 ssh keys corresponding to the email addresses for the profiles and added them to the respective keys.

Then, I configured the ~/.ssh/config as follows:

```
# Personal account, - the default config
Host github.com-personal
   HostName github.com
   User git
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519_personal
   
# Professional account
Host github.com-professional   
   HostName github.com
   User git
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_professional
```

However, when I fork a repo and try to git push, I keep getting this error:

```
To github.com:personal/repo.git
 ! [remote rejected] main -> main (permission denied)
error: failed to push some refs to 'github.com:personal/repo.git'
```

I am unsure what I'm doing wrong and github has constantly been a pain for me. Please help

Comment: You need to use that host in the remote url. Try swapping `github.com:personal` with `github.com-personal:personal`?

Comment: @evolutionxbox I tried that and still get  ! [remote rejected] main -> main (permission denied)
Do I need to do something to propagate the changes from the config file besides simply editing it and saving it ?

Comment: Did you add your ssh key to the github account? Test the connection with `ssh -Tv github.com-personal`

Answer (score 1):

To clarify the comments, if you have clone an upstream repository locally, and now want to push to a remote GitHub fork that you have created, the command would be:

```
cd /path/to/local/cloned/repository
git remote set-url github.com-personal:personal/repo.git
```

But, as noted, that supposes the ~/.ssh/id_ed25519_personal.pub (your public key) was [registered to your `personal` GitHub SSH settings](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account).